# Xpath - Select Text Node after a Tag

Tags: html, xpath

Why does this not work, I've searched other solutions which seem to point to the same expression as what I've come up with but it just won't work for me.

My XPath is

```
//b/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

My HTML:

```
<b>Foo1</b> Bar 1 <br/><br/>
<b>Foo2</b> Bar 2 <br/><br/>
```

Comment: Returns `" Bar 1 "` and `" Bar 2 "` for me. What do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell which environment your are using to execute the XPath query, but you may just need to drop the escaping backslashes in front of the brackets `[]`. (I have never seen that syntax before).

Here comes an example in PHP, which is using `XPath1.0`, the lowest XPath version, meaning it has no "fancy" stuff in it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('
<b>Foo1</b> Bar 1 <br/><br/>
<b>Foo2</b> Bar 2 <br/><br/>
');

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($selector->query('//b/following-sibling::text()[1]') as $e) {
    var_dump($e->nodeValue);
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) " Bar 1 "
string(7) " Bar 2 "
```

Comment: Got it working, returns expected text nodes using C# Agility Pack, for some reason the online tool doesn't highlight Text Nodes

Comment: This tool is insufficient. Use a programming language to test if you want to make sure that the results a compatible with a certain XPath standard. Current standards are 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 (but the latter is rarely deployed)

Comment: I use it all the time to quickly test expressions and it's served me well till now, guess it's not good when looking for text nodes